# How to use CASE WHEN to get matching SKU products from our assortment and our competition assortment

Tags: sql

I have a file with our competitor's product_id matched with our grocery store's product_id.  However, in addition to the product_id column we also have a "EPD" column which is a number similar to a barcode in Norway.  I have found 85 products for which there is no product_id for our assortment matched to the competitor product_id, BUT there is a match on the EPD number between our product and competitor product.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to fill in the our product_id in the case that we do have a match on the EPD.

Here is the structure of the data: There are 2 main tables I am using (1) **stg_tienda_products** which has all the products in our assortment and (2)**stg_tienda_external_products** which has all of our competitor assortment. These 2 are matched through the "product_id" column which is our unique code for the product in our assortment.

**stg_tienda_products**
[stg_tienda_products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BZZ9.png)

**stg_tienda_external_products**
[stg_tienda_external_products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03y1D.png)

This is the code I am using, but it is not adding the 85 rows with matching eps.

````
```
with epd_match as (
  select
    ep.external_product_id,
    ep.product_id as product_id1,
    p.product_id as product_id2,
    nullif(ep.epd,'')as rema_epd,
    nullif(p.epd,'')as oda_epd,
    case when rema_epd is not null then product_id1 = product_id2 else product_id1
  end as oda_sku
  from stg_tienda_external_products as ep
  left join stg_tienda_products as p on ep.epd = p.epd
  where ep.product_id is null and rema_epd is not null and oda_epd is not null 
  order by ep.external_product_id
)

--there are 85 products that have an epd match with rema, but no oda product_id in
 external_products_product table, need to add these matches in

select 
  ep.external_product_id as rema_sku,
  ep.product_id,
  em.rema_epd,
  em.oda_epd,
  pp.name as name,
  pb.name as brand,
  ep.ean as ean,
  ep.epd as epd

from stg_tienda_external_products as ep
left join epd_match as em on em.external_product_id=ep.external_product_id
left join stg_products_product as pp on ep.product_id = pp.product_id
left join stg_products_brand as pb on pp.brand_id = pb.id
left join stg_product_legalities_productjurisdictionstatus as j on 
j.product_id = pp.product_id  -- current jurisdiction attribution
left join stg_core_jurisdiction as jr on j.jurisdiction_id = jr.id
 -- jurisdiction catalog

where external_store_chain_id = 2 and ep.product_id is not NULL 
and jr.name='Norway'
order by oda_sku asc```
````

Comment: You claim that there are 85 missing records where the epd is equal, right? If so - where is the join on the epd column? I suggest adding it to the epd_match with clause and use it as a condition to the left join (something like left join epd_match as em on em.external_product_id=ep.external_product_id or epd = epd)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data to show the results you are receiving and what you are expecting/wanting? I think I know what you are looking for, but examples would help clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I am still a student, but this looks like you need the COALESCE command.  COALESCE replaces one value with another when the first value is null.

This [Transact-SQL article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) discusses COALESCE and its relationship with CASE.  It also gives several code examples.

I hope this gets you moving in the right direction.